# SwiftUI : Where changing a @State doesn't refresh the view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've an app based on SwiftUI that is puzzling me.  One of its Views has a @State variable which is used in a computation to create a Path which is displayed in a Context View.  That variable is changed on a timer and I expect the View to update when that happens.

But the main `FootprintView` View doesn't refresh unless I make that variable (`jdNow`) an explicit part of the View rendering hierarchy.  In the code below, the View doesn't refresh unless that `Text` View, containing the variable, is present .. remove it and refreshing stops.

I'm confident the assorted methods (which I've not shown here) called in the computation  are correct as evidenced by correct rendering when the `Text` View is present (and their use in other apps).  My current work-around is to keep the `Text` but make it invisible, with `.opacity(0.0)`.

Why?  I checked that the `.onReceive` decoration does fire to change the variable with, or without, the `Text` present, so the @State **is** changing.  I'm clearly not understanding some aspect of how @State works .. could someone educate me, please?

```
struct FootprintView: View {

    @State private var jdNow: Double = Date.now.julianDate

    var body: some View {

        Text("\(jdNow)").opacity(0.0)   //## needed to force the periodic redraw (why) ..

        Canvas { context, size in
            let mercatorContext = context.mercatorCoords(size)    // change to Mercator coordinates ..

            let visualGroup =  . . .

            for elements in visualGroup. . . {
                let satellite = Satellite(elements: elements)

                let minsAfterEpoch = (jdNow - JD.epoch1950 - satellite.t₀Days1950) * 1440.0
                let satCel = satellite.position(minsAfterEpoch: minsAfterEpoch)
                let satLLH = eci2geo(julianDays: jdNow, celestial: satCel)

                let footprintPath = drawFootprint(satGeo: satLLH)
                mercatorContext.stroke(footprintPath, with: .color(.white), lineWidth: 0.2)
            }
        }
        .onReceive(global5SecTimer) { _ in
            jdNow = Date.now.julianDate
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include a [mre]? It's unclear what that global timer is, what thread it runs on, etc. Also unclear if the Canvas has anything to do with this -- if not, remove it, since it relies on types that you haven't included here.

Comment: Make jdnow the id for the Canvas

Comment: I appreciate the value of a minimal, reproducible example and if I have no joy from my reading and experimenting, I'll take that option. For now, recognizing I'm not necessarily helping, the timer is `Timer.publish(every: 5, tolerance: 0.1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()` and the Canvas is rendering the quite complicated graphics for my app.  In my reading I noticed that Canvas performs "immediate mode drawing" and I wonder if that implies that it ignores @State changes ..

Comment: Your `Text` and `Canvas` views are inside `body` but they need to be aggregated into a single view.  Try using `VStack` on them.

Answer (score 1):

`body` is only called when a state's setter is called if its getter has been previously called. This is part of SwiftUI's dependency tracking.

In your case the state getter isn't called until you add the debug `Text`. This usually happens when you haven't designed your source of truth correctly. Since `body` only reads a date defined elsewhere you should pass it into your `View` as a `let`, e.g.

```
struct FootprintView: View {

    let jdNow: Double
```

`body` will be called every time `FootprintView` is init with a different `jdNow`, no need for `onReceive`. Think of `body` like an "any let or var has changed".

FYI to update on a timer in SwiftUI, the easiest way is [`TimelineView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/timelineview), e.g.

```
TimelineView(.periodic(from: startDate, by: 5)) { context in
    FootprintView(jdNow: context.date.julianDate)
}
```

Comment: Nice explanation.  Nice solution!  I just discovered `TimelineView` last night, watching many WWDC sessions, and it is exactly what I needed.  It allowed me to 'raise' the source of truth (the time) in the view hierarchy (the View illustrated above is only one of several `overlays`) and use it in several placed.  Thank you.

Comment: In passing .. I watched many WWDC sessions and read much documentation but I must be blind or stupid because "`body` is only called when a state's setter is called if its getter has been previously called" didn't get my notice.  If it had, my whole question here would have been unnecessary!

Answer (score -1):

An option you could pose is creating a `@State lazy var path = {<#Get State from your origin View here#>}` where you forward the State to your active view, This will likely solve your issue and allow update forwarding to your active view. If this doesn’t work you may want to publish a stack Trace here so we can parse it.

Do note this will forward changes of state where you can place in your relevant location (Band-Aid Solution), If this is not relevant please let me know